# Maven creates an empty folder instead of get the appropriate .jar

Tags: java, maven

Maven creates an empty folder instead of get the appropriate .jar.

I have a project that consists of 3 modules: one of the modules is the common part to the other two. While two modules produce WAR files, the third must produce a JAR which should be embedded in the other two WEB-INF/lib folder.

The JAR project is a simple "library" project. When I end my job I run a "install" goal to put that on my local repository, and it's work ! Other  prject see them, can use its classes and all other stuff. When I try to build a WAR file, maven copy all dependencies into WEB-INF/lib folder as jar file, except my third project. Maven create an empty folder named as my project with ".jar" suffix.

How can I fix it ?

My WAR project pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>it.m2sc.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>LiveDocs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>UIM</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>UIM</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cxf.version>2.2.2</cxf.version>
    <spring.version>2.5.6</spring.version>
    <webapp.path>src/main/webapp/</webapp.path>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- UIMDomain -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.m2sc.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>UIMDomain</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Adobe dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe</groupId>
        <artifactId>adobe-livecycle-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe</groupId>
        <artifactId>adobe-repository-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe</groupId>
        <artifactId>adobe-usermanager-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Base dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache CXF dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensymphony.quartz</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib-ext-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>UIMBack</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Compile -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Build -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I experience a very similar problem with `maven-war-plugin:3.2.2`. My Web project has an overridden `finalName`, and a `manifest` `addClasspath=true` configuration too.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me:

In project's setting file

```
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
```

removed the following line:

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent"/>
```

The Maven dependency description (which failed beforehand) follows the /WebContent one. Like this:

```
<dependent-module archiveName="____.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/____">
    <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
```

Any idea how this magic happened?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the relevance of this answer. The OP doesn't use Eclipse when they experience the problem.